# Blog Posts link to homepage instead of post – any new post and any from old site (Chrome / Firefox)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm Sarah and I have a Wordpress site with a custom theme on caroldonahoe.com.  Everything works fine in Safari, but posts on the second page of the blog (or those that came from her prior site) all redirect to the homepage when viewing in Chrome or Firefox. Same holds true for any category links.

Front page is set to 'Home' and post page is set to 'Blog'.  Permalink structure is set to month/name

The inspector suggests the correct link so I'm pretty stumped as to why it redirects to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a 'More' link, one of those 'after the jump' links in WP that was causing a 302 redirect to the homage. Simply removing these from the troublesome posts made the links actually link through to their post.

Safari was smart enough to see past the link redirect, Chrome and Firefox just made a loop.